# A cron job to change file permisssion

Tags: shell, shell-script

when i run chmod 777 to change permission of a file manually it runs. but when i put it in a cron job, it never changes the permission.

```
#!/bin/bash

YESTERDAY=`TZ=aaa24 date +%Y-%m-%d`

chmod 777 Overscratchcard_Detail_Report_*.csv
```

then i put above on a crontab to change the permission of the file, when i run manually the files permission changes, but on a cron job.... file still retains same permission.

Comment: use the full path to the file

Answer (score 1):

Cron has a shell of its own. So when you run a cron job it might not have the same environment as when your user executes it.
It is also good to give the full path of the file you are trying to modify.
You can try two things:
Source your users .bashrc to get the user environment.
Or 
Give the full path to chmod, I can't remember the full path but the command would look something like:

```
/usr/bin/chmod 777 /path-to-file/your.csv
```

To find the path to chmod you can run:

```
which chmod
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to write a shell script that actually does the chmod and call that with cron witht he times you like

If you have a script called /opt/foo/changeperms.sh, then you would call it from cron  with

```
* 1 * * * /opt/foo/changeperms.sh &
```

The & runs the script in background

Comment: You don't need to (and indeed shouldn't) run a cron job in the background

Comment: @roaima +1 and he can redirect output to /dev/null to not receive emails or log the result to logs.